# Exchange 2010 SP1 Auto Discover Service

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I have a test exchange 2010 SP1 server also running as a domain controller. We are going to use it as a development exchange server to test our own Exchange related developments against.

The domain works fine, as does exchange. It can route emails etc between accounts without issue. Connecting Outlook 2010 / 2003 and using the OWA works fine locally on the server and on remote machines. This doesn't have an internet facing route, it's not required.

In order to develop against the API provided by Exchange, we need to use the Auto Discover services. However the auto discover service appears not to be working.

If I navigate to "https://davedc/Autodiscover/autodiscover.xml" in my browser from another machine, I'm **not prompted** for authentication, and I'm presented with the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
  <Response>
    <Error Time="11:17:04.4201807" Id="2459279933">
      <ErrorCode>600</ErrorCode>
      <Message>Invalid Request</Message>
      <DebugData />
    </Error>
  </Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

I then used PS to diagnose the service with: Test-OutlookWebServices -ClientAccessServer "davedc" and was returned:

```
   RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1019
Type       : Information
Message    : A valid Autodiscover service connection point was found. The Autodiscover URL on this object is https://da
             vedc/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml.

RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1013
Type       : Error
Message    : When contacting https://davedc/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml received the error The remote server returned
              an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1023
Type       : Error
Message    : The Autodiscover service couldn't be contacted.

RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1113
Type       : Error
Message    : When contacting https://davedc.exch.local:443/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml received the error The remote
             server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1123
Type       : Error
Message    : The Autodiscover service couldn't be contacted.

RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1013
Type       : Error
Message    : When contacting https://davedc/EWS/Exchange.asmx received the error Client found response content type of
             '', but expected 'text/xml'.
             The request failed with an empty response.

RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1025
Type       : Error
Message    : [EXCH] Error contacting the AS service at https://davedc/EWS/Exchange.asmx. Elapsed time was 15 millisecon
             ds.

RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1026
Type       : Success
Message    : [EXCH] Successfully contacted the UM service at https://davedc/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed time was 15
             milliseconds.

RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1113
Type       : Error
Message    : When contacting https://davedc.exch.local/EWS/Exchange.asmx received the error Client found response conte
             nt type of '', but expected 'text/xml'.
             The request failed with an empty response.

RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1125
Type       : Error
Message    : [Server] Error contacting the AS service at https://davedc.exch.local/EWS/Exchange.asmx. Elapsed time was
             15 milliseconds.

RunspaceId : daaf1eca-c47e-4069-8e70-6c3816d240dd
Id         : 1126
Type       : Success
Message    : [Server] Successfully contacted the UM service at https://davedc.exch.local/EWS/Exchange.asmx. The elapsed
              time was 0 milliseconds.
```

I removed auto discovery VD

```
Remove-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory -Identity "davedc\autodiscover (Default Web Site)" -Confirm:$false
```

Then recreated

```
New-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory -WebsiteName "Default Web Site" -InternalUrl "https://davedc/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml" -BasicAuthentication 1 -WindowsAuthentication 1

Set-ClientAccessServer -Identity davedc -AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri "https://davedc/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml"
```

Get-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory reports a internal URL, but the test outlook web services results remain the same.

What can I do to get Autodiscover to work correctly?

[edited completely as I discovered that the MS publish command syntax was different from the syntax I needed to run]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. One of my colleagues while trying to resolve the issue has created an additional SSL port in IIS under the default website. (i didn't know this / realize this can cause an issue)

Combing the event logs, I found this entry.

```
The service '/Autodiscover/autodiscover.xml' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: This collection already contains an address with scheme https.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection.
```

Removing the additional SSL binding from the website resolved the issue. Auto discovery now works.

Comment: You saved my life. I was turning around since 2 days. I had an alternative https port binding wich was causing the error 500. Thank you !